# Combining single and repeated variables in protobuff for Python parsing

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

A colleague of mine has serialized a protobuff file based on the following schema:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "timestamp.proto";

message PSessionLogs {
    // from Root proto
    int32 EntityType = 1;      
    string SessionID = 2;       
    repeated PSessionLogsDetail LogDetail = 3;
}

message PSessionLogsDetail {
    google.protobuf.Timestamp DataTimestamp = 1;

    // Sensory data
    int32 Sens1 = 2;
    int32 Sens2 = 3;
    int32 Sens3 = 4;
}
```

Essentially, the message has a header (EntityType and SessionID) after which logging starts where 3 sensors are continuously sending a log message with a timestamp. Before serializing each sensor measurement, he creates a struct with the timestamp and 3 sensor data. What we want to do is to deserialize this log file in Python where we have a header and then a LogDetail member with timestamps and sensor data.

What I've tried to do is generate a .py file from the .proto file with protoc and use this .py as the following:

```
import PSessionLogs_pb2

with open('$PROTOBUF_LOG_FILENAME$', 'rb') as f:
    read_metric =  PSessionLogs_pb2.PSessionLogs()
    read_metric.ParseFromString(f.read())
```

This gives me

> "DecodeError: Truncated message."

The log also seems to be overwriting the value of EntityType with the timestamp value.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?